# Matching File/Directory Path formats for both WINS32 and POSIX systems

Tags: node.js, typescript

I need to create a function that validates a given file/directory path. By validate, I mean that it just needs to be recognizable to the operating system. Whether the path itself exists is irrelevant for this context. So, here's what I got so far. But, its kind of failing...

```
import * as path from "path"
const RESTRICTED = /[\[\]#%&{}<>*?\s\b\0$!'"@|‘“+^`]/g;
const WINDOWS_RESTRICTED = /[\\:]/g;
const POSIX_RESTRICTED = /[\/]/g;

const isValid = (suspect: string): boolean => {
    const containsRestrictedCharacters = RESTRICTED.test(suspect) || process.platform == "win32" ? WINDOWS_RESTRICTED.test(suspect) : POSIX_RESTRICTED.test(suspect);
        console.log(containsRestrictedCharacters ? "Has invalid character" : "No invalid characters" + " on" + process.platform);
        const absoluteBeginning = /^([a-zA-Z]:\\|\/|\~\/)/;
        const relativeBeginning = /^(?:\.\\|\.\/|\.\.\\|\.\.\/)/;
        const validBeginning = path.isAbsolute(suspect) ? absoluteBeginning.test(suspect) : relativeBeginning.test(suspect);
        console.log(validBeginning ? "Begining is valid." : "Invalid beginning");
        return !containsRestrictedCharacters && validBeginning;
}

const valid = isValid("this/is/a/valid/file/path");
console.log(valid ? "Path is valid" : "Path is invalid.");
```

The function needs to be able to test both absolute paths and relative paths. From this test, it is saying that the (relative) path both contains invalid characters and the beginning is invalid. I do expect this test to pass though. So, I'd appreciate some suggestions for how I can approach this better. This way is just not working. I also tried to see if there was some regex I can use. However, I can't seem to find one that works for both wind32 and POSIX systems.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am honestly not even sure if this is the right approach. So, if you have a better solution,  I am all ears. :)

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/anodynos/upath